# phpMyAdmin user levels

Tags: php, mysql

I found [this](http://www.1stoptutorials.com/Create-Members-Area-Lesson10.html) tutorial to create a members only area on my webpage using phpMyAdmin. The only problem I have is I need to have different pages show for different user levels. Currently all my users are user level 0, I would like to create an admin user as user level 1. I believe the php file I need to change is the one below, it is my checkuser.php file. Any help or direction would be much appreciated! Thanks in advance.

```
    <?
/* Check User Script */
session_start();  // Start Session

include 'db.php';
// Conver to simple variables
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

if((!$username) || (!$password)){
    echo "";
    include 'loginError.php';
    exit();
}

// check if the user info validates the db
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password' AND activated='1'");
$login_check = mysql_num_rows($sql);

if($login_check > 0){
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    foreach( $row AS $key => $val ){
        $$key = stripslashes( $val );
    }
        // Register some session variables!
        session_register('first_name');
        $_SESSION['first_name'] = $first_name;
        session_register('last_name');
        $_SESSION['last_name'] = $last_name;
        session_register('email_address');
        $_SESSION['email_address'] = $email_address;
        session_register('special_user');
        $_SESSION['user_level'] = $user_level;

        mysql_query("UPDATE users SET last_login=now() WHERE userid='$userid'");

        header("Location: /restricted/index.php");
    }
} else {
    echo "";
    include 'loginError.php';
}
?>
```

Comment: Think about what you want to do. You want to check a users level, then you want to make a decision about what a user can see based on their level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple if

```
session_start();
if($_SESSION['user_level']==0){
    header('location: no-access.php');
}
```

This will redirect user with level zero to no-access page. Put this top of page you want to restrict.